# Select Count using Criteria builder in a OneToMany Relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm, entitymanager

I'm building a Spring web app and i'm new to JPA and I need to get the number of users in a specific group in my database.

Here is the sample code :

```
public long countAllUsersByGroup(int groupId) {
    CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = qb.createQuery(Long.class);
    cq.select(qb.count(cq.from(User.class)));
    //cq.where(qb.equal(cq.from(User.class).get("userGroup").get("id"),groupId));
    return em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
}
```

This code is working, it allows me to retrieve the number of users I have in the database which is pretty trivial.

This is my user Model :

```
public class User {
    private String userFirstName;
    private String userLastName; 
    /* some stuff */
    @ManyToOne
    private Group userGroup;
    }
```

And my group model has an int attribute annotated with `@Id` and named `id`. How Can I get the number of user by group id in this case ?

P.S : I've tried and commented my try in the code above, unfortunately it was a failure ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
  CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

  CriteriaQuery<Long> q = cb.createQuery(Long.class);

  ParameterExpression<Integer> p = cb.parameter(Integer.class);
  q.select(q.count(q.from(User.class))).where(cb.gt(c.get("userGroup"), someId));
```

Comment: The method count(Root<User>) is undefined for the type CriteriaQuery<Long> ... What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: And the ParameterExpression is not used ? What's the purpose then ?

Comment: And from where did you come with the variable " c " !

Comment: C here is cb, sorry for the confusion